# Creating python dictionary that maps each domain to multiple coded values in File Geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, dictionary, domains

I have a File GDB that has domains and coded values. I would like to extract those values from the GDB and build a dictionary. For example:

I have hundreds of domains and with each domain has a set of coded values associated with it.

```
*Domain* , *Coded Value*
['tree', 'pine']
['tree', 'magnolia']
['tree', 'fir']
['tree', 'grey pine']
['tree', 'oak']
['soil', 'clay']
['soil', 'loam']
['soil', 'sandy']
['brush', 'manz']
['brush', 'short']
['water', 'wetland']
['water', 'lake']
etc.....
```

I want this:

```
{'tree': ['pine', 'magnolia', 'fir', 'grey pine']}
{'soil': ['clay', 'loam', 'sandy']}
{'brush': ['manz', 'short']}
{'water': ['wetland', 'lake']}
```

How do i accomplish this by using arcpy.da.ListDomains? This is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy

doms = arcpy.da.ListDomains(gdb)

    for dom in doms:

    if dom.domainType == 'CodedValue':
        codedvalues = dom.codedValues
        for code1 in codedvalues:

             list1 = []

             c_data = "{},{}".format(dom.name, code1)
             domain2 = c_data.split(",")[0]
             code2 = c_data.split(",")[1]

             list1 = [domain2, code2]
             print list1  #this prints out the first code block shown above
```

Comment: `{'tree': 'pine', 'magnolia', 'fir', 'grey pine'}` isn't a dictionary.  A dictionary is `{Key: Value}`, so you'd probably need a list to record the values e.g. `{'tree': ['pine', 'magnolia', 'fir', 'grey pine']}` to make it how you're suggesting

Comment: Yes I need: {'tree': ['pine', 'magnolia', 'fir', 'grey pine']}

Comment: To append values into your empty list you could use `.append()` on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
codedDomains = {domain.name: domain.codedValues.keys() for domain in arcpy.da.ListDomains(gdb) if domain.domainType == 'CodedValue'}
```

Basically, it uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to populate a dictionary, but only if it is a coded value domain. If you wanted to have it populated with the description instead of the coded value, replace the

```
domain.codedValues.keys()
```

with

```
domain.codedValues.values()
```

[This entry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/domain.htm) in the ArcGIS help may also give other options on domain objects that might be helpful.